# How can I conditionally add a Handlebars partial to an Assemble layout?

Tags: handlebars.js, assemble

I'm using [Assemble](http://assemble.io/) along with [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/) to generate a static site. I have a handful of pages that use the same general layout, with a couple of exceptions where content outside of the main `{{> body}}` needs to be added.

Given this generic page structure:

```
<html>
<body>

<section>{{> body}}</section>

<!-- global scripts -->

</body>
</html>
```

and the need for `index.html` to have markup added between `<!-- global scripts -->` and `</body>`, **what's the best way to go about it?**

If I include a partial in my Gruntfile like so:

```
index: {
    options: {
        partials: ['source/partials/home/**/*.hbs'],
    },
    files: [{
        expand: true,
        cwd: 'source/pages/',
        src: '**/index.hbs',
        dest: 'output/'
    }],
},
```

this partial is available to all other subsequent items in the `assemble` task, which I certainly don't want. If this was simply a variable, I could do it in YML front matter or something like that, but it's a block of HTML and inline JS and thus is a bit more than I would want to put in front matter. I also cannot load this markup via JS as it needs to be blocking.

Answer (score 2):

You could add a variable to the frontmatter of the pages that need the partial included, like this:

```
specialHTML: true
```

and then add in your code

```
{{#if specialHTML}}
    {{> mypartial }}
{{/specialHTML}}
```

so the partial would only be added if you set the "SpecialHTML" in the frontmatter.